# Java - Trying to create an arraylist of strings but the arraylist gets full(?)

Tags: java, arraylist

I might just be doing something stupid here but I'm trying to write a program that will take all the text from an xml file, put it in an arraylist as strings, then find certain recurring strings and count them. It basically works, but for some reason it won't go through the entire xml file. It's a pretty large file with over 15000 lines (ideally I'd like it to be able to hand any amount of lines though). I did a test to output everything it was putting in the arraylist to a .txt file and eventually the last line simply says "no", and there's still much more text/lines to go through.

This is the code I'm using to make the arraylist (lines is the amount of lines in the file):

```
    // make array of strings
for (int i=0; i<lines; i++) {
   strList.add(fin2.next());
}
fin2.close();
```

Then I'm searching for the desired strings with:

```
    // find strings
for (String string : strList) {
   if(string.matches(identifier)){
      count++;
   }
}
System.out.println(count);
fout.println(count);
```

It basically works (the printwriter and scanners work, line count works, etc) except the arraylist won't take all the text from the .xml file, so of course the count at the end is inaccurate. Is arraylist not the best solution for this problem?

Comment: I think fin2 is a Scanner ("the printwriter and scanners work") but in that case, I have no idea why it's being closed.

Comment: It would be best if you post a minimal but complete program that we can reproduce as well.  Otherwise, we're just guessing what's wrong.

Answer (score 1):

This is a **BAD** practice to do. Each time you put a string into an ArrayList and keep it there, you're going to have an increase in memory usage. The bigger the file, the more memory is used up to the point where you're wondering why your application is using 75% of your memory.

You don't need to store the lines into an ArrayList in order to see if they match. You can simply just read the line and compare it to whatever text you're comparing it to.

Here would be your code modified:

```
String nextString = "";
while (fin2.hasNext()) {
    nextString = fin2.next();
    if (nextString.matches(identifier) || nextString.matches(identifier2)) {
        count++;
    }
}
fin2.close();
System.out.pritnln(count);
```

Eliminates looping through everything twice, saves you a ton of memory, and gives you accurate results. Also I'm not sure if you're meaning to read the entire line, or you have some sort of token. If you want to read the entire line, change `hasNext` to `hasNextLine` and `next` to `nextLine`

Edit: Modified the code to show what it would look like looking for multiple strings.

Comment: This seems like it would fix the issue, but it makes it so I can't run the same code a few times to search for other strings without having to make a bunch of scanners. I want to be able to search for several different strings in the file, which is why I was putting the lines in an arraylist first.

Comment: Edited the snippet allowing you to use multiple search terms. If you have a large amount of search terms, you can just have an array of search terms and loop through them comparing them to nextString inside the while loop.

Comment: I need each found search term to have its own count though, I probably should have said that before.

Comment: `String[] searchTerms =` ........ not sure how many you're going through.
`int[] searchCounts = new int[searchTerms.length];` Then you can just loop through the terms, and update the ith searchCount each time you find something with the ith searchPhrase.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use map, like HashMap. Since Your goal is to find the occurrence of word from a xml, hashmap will make your like easier.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with your ArrayList but with your for loop. What's happening is that you're using the number of lines in your file as your sentinel value, but rather than incrementing i by 1 every line, you are doing it every word. Therefore, not all the words are added to your ArrayList because your loop terminates earlier than expected. Hope this helps!

EDIT: I don't know what object you are using right now to collect the contents of this xml file, but I would suggest using Scanner instead (passing the File as a parameter in the constructor) and replacing the current for loop with a while loop that uses `while (nameOfScanner.hasNextLine())`